# Why expression results are different?

Tags: perl, operator-precedence

executing perl program I get different results:

```
$ perl -e 'my $i = 2; $i += 2 + $i++; print "$i\n"'
7
$ perl -e 'my $i = 2; $i += $i + $i++; print "$i\n"'
8
```

Why results are different? what did I miss in second case? I expect `7` in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl does not guarantee any specific result for either snippets you posted, and you should avoid such code.

---

That said, the behaviour is consistent across all existing builds of Perl.

While this isn't documented or guaranteed, Perl always evaluates the left-hand side (LHS) of addition operators before their right-hand side (RHS).<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e 'my $i = 2; $i += $i + $i++; print "$i\n"'
...
8  <0> padsv[$i:1,2] s       > LHS
9  <0> padsv[$i:1,2] sRM     \ RHS
a  <1> postinc[t2] sK/1      /
b  <2> add[t3] sK/2
...
```

So why does it seem like that's not the case?

The key to understanding what is going on is that the Perl stack only contains scalars (`SV*`, including subtypes such as `AV*`). That means that `$i` places the actual scalar associated with `$i` on the stack, not merely the value `2`.<sup>[2]</sup>

That means that even though `$i` is evaluated and placed on the stack before `$i++` is evaluated and placed on the stack, the updated value of `$i` will be used by the addition operator.

```
    $i  stack
    --  -----
     2
$i
     2  $i
$i
     2  $i,$i
postinc
     3  $i,2
add
     3  5
```

---

If you want, you can trace what's happening with replication of the Perl interpreter:

```
use Data::Alias qw( alias );

my @stack;
my @pad;

sub padsv {
   my $padidx = shift;
   alias push @stack, $pad[$padidx];
}

sub postinc {
   alias my $sv = pop(@stack);
   alias my $result = $sv++;
   alias push @stack, $result;
}

sub add {
   alias my ($lhs, $rhs) = splice(@stack, -2);
   alias my $result = $lhs + $rhs;
   alias push @stack, $result;
}


{ my $i = 2; say $i + $i++; }  # 5

$pad[0] = 2;
padsv(0); padsv(0); postinc(); add();
say pop(@stack);  # 5


{ my $i = 1; say $i + $i++ + $i++; }  # 5

$pad[0] = 1;
padsv(0); padsv(0); postinc(); add(); padsv(0); postinc(); add();
say pop(@stack);  # 5
```

Alternative:

```
sub postinc :lvalue { $_[0]++ }
sub add :lvalue { $_[0] + $_[1] }

{ my $i = 2; say $i + $i++;            } # 5
{ my $i = 2; say add($i, postinc($i)); } # 5

{ my $i = 1; say $i + $i++ + $i++;                       } # 5
{ my $i = 1; say add(add($i, postinc($i)), postinc($i)); } # 5
```

---

1. Note that this contradicts the [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49597407/589924). Its explanation of what happens is completely wrong and disproven by `$i + $i++ + $i++`.
2. This is done for performance reasons. Making a copy of a scalar is expensive, and doing so for every scalar placed on the stack would have a severe negative impact on performance.

Comment: Why when we have value at specific point perl do not put it on the stack instead of scalar? Would it be more correct?

Comment: I mean we can put a copy of scalar with value at that time. and do not put origin scalar over and over.

Comment: Making a copy is expensive. Making a copy of everything put on the stack would have a severe negative impact on performance. Instead, languages don't define exact semantics for code such as yours. [This comment added was incorporated into my answer.]

Comment: And no, it wouldn't be "more correct". There's no mathematical basis for either approach.

Comment: "each" - it will be too much. Just put a copy for scalar which is changed ( assign, increment, decrement ops ). Despite on there is no mathematical basic it would be interesting to involve into this. I should try this! =) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The autoincrement is done first, leaving `$i + $i++` equal to `3 + 2`

You shouldn't use expressions like this where the semantics are unclear. You should split the calculation across multiple statements.

Comment: huh.... Perl doesn't define when the variable is incremented or decremented: `my $i = 1; $i += $i + $i++ + $i++; print "$i\n"`. Result: 8

Comment: @EugenKonkov funny, I would have expected either 7 or 9. But yeah, hairy and not something you should play with :)